# SwiftyJSON - How to loop through child nodes when parsing

Tags: ios, json, swift, parsing, swifty-json

I have the below JSON structure that I'm attempting to parse using SwiftyJSON, but I can't work out how to loop through the "sections" node. The code I currently have returns the first section node for each section, but I can't access the "Section 1b / Section 2b" elements.

```
{
"category": [{
    "categoryId": 1,
    "categoryHeader": "Category 1",
    "sections": [{
        "section": "Section 1a title",
        "body": "Section 1a body"
    }, {
        "section": "Section 1b title",
        "body": "Section 1b body"
    }]
}, {
    "categoryId": 2,
    "categoryHeader": "Category 2",
    "sections": [{
        "section": "Section 2a title",
        "body": "Section 2a body"
    },{
        "section": "Section 2a title",
        "body": "Section 2b body"
    }]
}]

}
```

My code is:

```
let path: String = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("jsonFile", ofType: "json") as String!
let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: path) as NSData!

var objects = [[String: String]]()
let json = JSON(data: data)

 func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
    for category in json["category"].arrayValue {
        let categoryHeader = category["categoryHeader"].stringValue
        let section = category["sections"][0]["section"].stringValue
        let sectionBody = category["sections"][0]["body"].stringValue
        let obj = ["categoryHeader": categoryHeader, "section": section, "body": sectionBody] //, "body": body, "title": sigs]

    objects.append(obj)
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I know I need to loop through the sections part to retrieve all values but I can't work out how to.

**Edit:**
Attempting to do so with the following allows me to access all the sections nodes; but then the 'categoryHeader' is output 'x' times depending on how many sections there are:

```
func parseJSON(json: JSON) {
    for category in json["category"].arrayValue {
        let categoryHeader = category["categoryHeader"].stringValue

        for section in category["sections"].arrayValue {
            let sectionName = section["section"].stringValue
            let body = section["body"].stringValue
            let obj = ["categoryHeader": categoryHeader, "section": sectionName, "body": body]   
    objects.append(obj)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing it could be like this.

**EDIT: I have this code work in a play ground.**

```
var objects = [[String: String]]()


func parseJSON(json: JSON) {

    let jsonResults = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .MutableContainers) as! NSDictionary
    let json = JSON.self(jsonResults)
   // let json = JSON(data: data) // moved this line
   let count: Int? = json.dictionary?.count

   let ct = 0
   if  ct < count {
     for index in 0...count!-1 {
       for category in json["category"].arrayValue {
        let categoryHeader = category["categoryHeader"].stringValue
        let section = category["sections"][0]["section"].stringValue
        let sectionBody = category["sections"][0]["body"].stringValue
        let obj = ["categoryHeader": categoryHeader, "section": section, "body": sectionBody] //, "body": body, "title": sigs]

        objects.append(obj)
      }
   }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: What is the value of json.array?.count meant to represent? It's currently coming back as nil so never executing the statements that follow. Sorry if I've missed something...

Comment: See the edit. It supposed to count the number of sections in the array.

Comment: Ah ok thanks I see. Making that amendment, the let json = JSON(data:data) errors with "Use of unresolved identifier 'data'".

Comment: How are you retrieving the json information? See the post update and see if that would help.

Comment: I've updated the code snippet in the question to show how I'm getting the json. Applying the latest code change still has issues with 'data'.

Comment: My project is still complaining about 'data'...but in a separate instance it seems to be working better...I'll try and debug my project further :) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Would:

```
for section in category["sections"].arrayValue {
    let sectionName = section["section"].stringValue
    let body = section["body"].stringValue
}
```

work?

Comment: I've updated the question with an edit on how I have attempted to implement this approach.